# How can we create a handler in UI thread for sending data to another thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 3 threads in android application.
1)UI thread
2)Server thread
3)Client thread

when a user enters a string and submits data from UI , I need to pass that data to server thread so that server will send it to clients , via bluetooth socket .

To send the data to server thread I am using the below code

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "send data to server handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Handler serverHandler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Message msg=new Message();
        msg.obj=text.getText();
        serverHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

In my understanding ,I need to create a handler from the looper related to server thread and send the message. 
**Can somebody advise if this is the right way of creating handler objects from looper.**

This is the server thread I am having

Looper.prepare();

```
                    serverHandler = new Handler() {
                        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            // Act on the message
                            String data=(String)msg.obj;
                            try {
                                socket.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    Looper.loop();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply .not yet tried  , will update

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any confusion, simply create an `AsyncTask`

```
  private class DataHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String message = null;
        private Socket socket;

        public DataHandler(String message, Socket socket) {
            this.message = message;
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

AsyncTask call

```
new DataHandler(text.getText(),socket).execute();
```